# Детский вопрос: подсолнух и солнце — это родственные слова?

Tags: словообразование, однокоренные-слова, морфемика, морфемный-разбор

Подсолнухи в этом году удались, вызрели.
"А почему подсолнух?" Объяснила ребенку, что это "солнечный цветок", что верхушка движется за солнцем, даже если его нет. От этих слов (солнце, солнечный) название и возникло.

Ан нет, у Тихонова, оказывается, совсем другое решение: корень **-подсолн-**; суффикс **-ух**.
А каково ваше мнение: подсолнух (подсолнечник) и солнце — это однокоренные слова?
Почему именно такой морфемный разбор у А. Н. Тихонова?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Безусловно, это этимологически родственные слова! Существительное *подсолнух* как название растения получилось либо в результате слияния предложно-падежного сочетания *под солнцем*, либо как переоформление старорусского *подсолношникъ* «зонтик».

Дело в том, что при морфемном разборе принято учитывать синхронные связи слов. Это значит, что, по мнению А. Н. Тихонова, слово *подсолнечник* потеряло свою связь с производящей основой *солнц(е)*, его морфемный состав упростился (произошло так называемое опрощение). Поэтому в *подсолнухе* и выделяется лишь корень *подсолн-*.

По материалам Этимологического словаря современного русского языка А. К. Шапошникова.

Answer (score 3):

У меня нет сомнений, что это однокоренные слова:
"**солнечная**" составляющая могла быть заимствована из латыни (видовое наименование Helianthus) или из английского (sunflower) после открытия Америки (родины всех подвидов П.) и перенесения вида в Россию, факт "следования за солнцем" (поворот *под* местоположение солнца) тоже вполне достоверен, и на него ссылаются *этимологические* словари (напр. Занимательный этимологический словарь. Н. М. Голь. 2007). Мнение автора другого словаря составителям школьных программ тоже известно:
http://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%9F/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%85

Comment: (Не в плане возражения) уточню, что следование цветов подсолнуха за солнцем (гелиотропизм) является одним из самых распространённых мифов о природе во многих культурах. Гелиотропизмом обладают только бутоны подсолнечника, зрелые цветы не двигаются и обычно направлены на восток.

Comment: Даже не бутоны, а растение в целом поворачивается, пока растёт. С зацветанием останавливается с цветком, развёрнутым на восток, как бы "навстречу" солнцу: https://nplus1.ru/news/2016/08/06/sunflower

Answer (score 1):

> Ан нет, у Тихонова, оказывается, совсем другое решение: корень
>   -подсолн-; суффикс -ух. А каково ваше мнение: подсолнух (подсолнечник) и солнце
>   — это однокоренные слова? Почему именно такой морфемный
>   разбор у А. Н. Тихонова?

Вас интересует, как правильно - или почему так у Тихонова?
На первый вопрос можно ответить определенно: **и то и другое правильно в рамках соответcтвующей системы представлений**.

А вот что касается Тихонова и его подхода... У него много противоречивого и откровенно непонятного. Если верить провозглашенной им концепции, то он при составлении словаря исповедовал синхронистский подход (как он его сам понимает), в частности - часто отбрасывал историческую морфологию слова в угоду простоте и понятности. 
О том, что такое синхронизм и диахронизм в лингвистике, см. тут. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F
Если кратно, при синхронии язык рассматривается в неком историческом срезе, AS IS на некоторый момент времени.

В слове "подсолнух" исторический морф "сол(н)" не воспринимается современными носителями языка как что-то семантически значимое, а приставка не вычленяется. Таким образом, согласно Тихонову, перед нами современный корневой морф **"подсолн"**. Конечно, это не совсем верно с исторической точки зрения, но позволяет изучающему язык школьнику удовлетворить практические нужды без глубокого анализа, требующего тех знаний, которых у такого школьника скорее всего нет.

Парадокс в том, что школьнику продвинутому, понимающему внутреннюю морфологию слова, невозможно объяснить (без привлечения понятия морфологического переразложения), почему дядя Тихонов не понимает элементарных вещей. 
Как тут быть, я не знаю.

Возможно, выручит то соображение, что при таком подходе понятия "родственные слова" и "однокоренные слова" не синонимичны. Как мы могли убедиться, "подсолнечник" слово **родственное** "солнцу", но **не однокоренное** с ним. Подчеркиваю, это только при синхонистском подходе Тихонова.

*А вообще это не самое страшное, что Тихонов учудил. Одно понятие "глагольного окончания" чего стоит. То есть само по себе оно и не страшно, хоть горшком назови, но из него вытекает, что у глаголов на "-еть" это "-еть" - окончание, а вот у глаголов на "-ить" - "окончание" только -ть, а -и- - суффикс. Это только пример тихоновского подхода, а "подсолнечник" - это только семечки. )))*

Answer (score 0):

> "А почему подсолнух?" Объяснила ребенку, что это "солнечный цветок", что верхушка движется за солнцем, даже если его нет. От этих слов (солнце, солнечный) название и возникло.

Ну да, верно. И сам цветок напоминает солнце, как его иногда рисуют.

Попробуем проще, без "синхронных связей слов", по-рабоче-крестьянски, для ребенка же... Подсолнух сейчас - это просто такой цветок, выделять в нем приставку ПОД- не очень-то оправдано. Ведь возникло новое словарное гнездо (не слишком, правда, большое): подсолнух, подсолнечник, подсолнечный. Вот и выделили новый корень ПОДСОЛН.

Comment: Выделил**и**? Кто ещё кроме г-на Тихонова выделил такой корень самостоятельно? Как они соотносят свою находку со словарной статьёй В. Даля: _НАДСОЛНЕЧНЫЙ, противопол. подсолнечный_-? Надпочечник и надпочечный  у них тоже имеют корень -надпочечн-?

Comment: Что такое "надсолнечный", понять трудно. Нешто есть такое слово? Хвастаться нехорошо, но и я бы выделил именно такой корень (подсолн), если бы у меня спросили.

Answer (score 0):

Схема образования слова: **солнце — под/солн/ух.** Но в качестве названия растения это слово получает **собственную семантику**, отличную от мотивирующего слова ***солнце***.

Поэтому, как я думаю, в этом значении это слово **вообще не надо разделять на морфемы**, по крайней мере, **вариант подсолн/ух не имеет никакого смысла.**

**Таким образом, формально это родственные слова, а семантически — нет.**

Можно сравнить со словом ***колокольчик***.

**КОЛОКОЛЬЧИК,**  м. 1. **Маленький колокол** (1 зн.). К. под дугой. Ручной к.  2. **Травянистое растение** с лиловыми или тёмно-голубыми цветками, похожими на маленький колокол. Лесные, садовые колокольчики.

И вот в значении "травянистое растение" мы же не будем выделять в слове ***колокольчик*** суффикс ЧИК.